# wrapping of variable when computing power with given base and exponent

Tags: c

This is what i have done but, some wrapping of variable is happening,thus, z becoming 0 or some negative value, and i am not able to overcome from the situation.

```
void pow(int64_t z,int64_t m)
{
  int64_t pow=1;
  while(m>0)
  {
    while(m>0 && m%2==0)
    {
      m=m-2;
      z=z*z;
    }
    m=m-1;
    pow=pow*z;
  }
  printf("value is %ld",pow);
}

int main()
{
  int64_t x,n;
  printf("Enter base and exponent\n");
  scanf("%ld %ld",&x,&n);
  pow(x,n);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

where z-->base
and m-->exponent.
I tried with long long which is provided by int64_t in  header file , but result is same.Can someone help me through this.

Comment: What behavior do you want to occur when the value overflows? Overflow is inevitable given large inputs.

Comment: well..that overflow can't be avoided but for values within overflow range..it should show right?...suppose if am giving values as 2 10 where base is 2 and exponent is 10, then it is returning me value as 1!!

Comment: Oh, I think I misinterpreted your question. I think you're asking why the code doesn't work. Is that correct? If so, can you describe what test cases you've run, what you've done to debug the code, etc.?

Comment: yes..there is something i guess i am doing wrong...upto 2 to the power 8..values are coming fine as z inside the function stays within 65536...but for rest such as 2 9 or 2 10..returning 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pow() function is nearly correct.
Nice planned use of squaring for efficient integer power function.
Code runs fast even with 1 9223372036854775807.  Much better than simple loop.

1.The `while()` loop where OP is squaring should be

```
// m=m-2;
m = m/2;
```

2.When using int64_t, use the correct format specifiers.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
...
// printf("value is %ld",pow);
printf("value is %" PRId64, pow);
...
// scanf("%ld %ld", &x, &n);
scanf("%" SCNd64 "%"  SCNd64, &x, &n);
```

3.OP should improve formatting

4.Avoid naming `pow()` as that is a standard math function

```
// void pow(int64_t z,int64_t m)
void RK_pow(int64_t z, int64_t m)
```

5.Recommend: check the result of `scanf()`.

```
// scanf("%ld %ld", &x, &n);
if (2 == scanf("%" SCNd64 "%"  SCNd64, &x, &n)) GoodToGo();
```

6.Recommend @twalberg idea: Make `m` an unsigned type or check for negativity.

7.Candidate simplification.  The `(m > 0)` is not needed as it it already known to be greater than 0 at first and on subsequent loops, with the `m/2` fix, it will not be 0.

```
//while (m > 0 && m % 2 == 0)
while (m % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: @RakeshKumar You also should validate that `m` is non-negative at the top, or switch to an unsigned type for it...

Comment: @chux i couldn't include <inttypes.h> for int64_t data type. I was previously including <stdint.h>, but the scanf/printf format you suggested is not working.but anyways thanks for pointing out the logical mistakes..:)

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar Alternative: `printf("value is %lld", (long long) pow)`.  For `scanf()`, it is more complicated.  Suggest creating your own `#ifdef SCNd64 #define RK_SCNd64 SCNd64 #else #define RK_SCNd64 "lld" #endif`, or something like that.